# How does C# manage memory allocated by a new operator inside a loop?

Tags: .net, memory-management, new-operator

For example:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   myclass = new myclass();
   // do stuff with myclass
}
```

Questions:

1. How will all the memory that has been allocated by doing 10 allocations in this case be retrieved?
2. What will my memory footprint be at the end of execution?
3. With delete functionality in C++, one had more control over this but in this case, for the second iteration, myclass would simply take a new allocation and move on?

Comment: FYI, this isn't a C# issue, it's a .NET issue.

Answer (score 7):

Since there are no more references to each new object after the next iteration*, they're eligible to be garbage-collected. But because you don't know *when* said garbage collection is going to happen, there's no straight answer as to what the memory footprint might be in the end.

Refer to [MSDN: Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) for more details.

<sub>* Unless the constructor adds a reference to the object somewhere it'll stick.</sub>

Comment: +1. Side note: In case when `myClass` is actually `struct` things will be different, but hopefully it is not the case.

Comment: Id like to add that the biggest benefit of using a managed language is that you don't have to worry about stuff like this.

Comment: @iamkrillin - correct, i actually have a C background in embedded systems so these questions came to me naturally ;)