# C# apps using ram and cannot be cleared

Tags: c#, memory-management

Okay, i had create an apps and the apps are eating ram too much.

The Problem:

- At the clearing process, i dispose the object but the ram usage isn't going down
- I don't have any idea, where is the mistake.

How the program works

- Started
- user press space -> screen captured, cropped, and snipped to screen.
- user press 1 -> clear all snipped image.

How the "space" works:

```
PictureBox frame = new PictureBox();
frame.Size = target.Size;
frame.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
frame.Image = get_img();
frame.Location = new Point(mouse.X - (target.Width / 2), mouse.Y - (target.Height / 2));
this.Controls.Add(frame);
frame.BringToFront();
box.Add(frame);
go_transparant();
```

How the "1" works:

```
foreach(var i in box){
   this.Controls.Remove(i);
   i.Dispose();
}
box.Clear();
box = new List<PictureBox>();
```

get_img function:

```
this.Visible = false;
using (Bitmap ss = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen()))
{
    this.Visible = true;

    result = ss.Clone(new Rectangle(mouse.X - target.Width / 2, mouse.Y - target.Height / 2, target.Width, target.Height),
    ss.PixelFormat);

    return result;
}
```

go_transparant function:

```
int wl = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle);
wl = wl | 0x80000 | 0x20;
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, wl);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, 0, 150, LWA.Alpha);
this.AllowTransparency = true;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Violet;
this.BackColor = Color.Violet;
```

FULL CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gma.UserActivityMonitor;

namespace LoA_Tarrot_Helper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public enum GWL
        {
            ExStyle = -20
        }

        public enum WS_EX
        {
            Transparent = 0x20,
            Layered = 0x80000
        }

        public enum LWA
        {
            ColorKey = 0x1,
            Alpha = 0x2
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
        public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLayeredWindowAttributes")]
        public static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hWnd, int crKey, byte alpha, LWA dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCursorPos")]
        public static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);

        private void go_transparant()
        {
            int wl = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle);
            wl = wl | 0x80000 | 0x20;
            SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, wl);
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, 0, 150, LWA.Alpha);
            this.AllowTransparency = true;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Violet;
            this.BackColor = Color.Violet;
        }
        private void prepare() 
        {
            target.Multiline = true;
            target.Enabled = false;
            target.Size = new Size(80, 80);
            target.BackColor = Color.Violet;
            this.Controls.Add(target);

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.TopMost = true;
        }
        TextBox target = new TextBox();
        List<PictureBox> box = new List<PictureBox>();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            prepare();
            go_transparant();
            timer1.Start();
            HookManager.KeyUp += HookManager_KeyUp;
        }
        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        Bitmap result;
        private Bitmap get_img() 
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            using (Bitmap ss = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen()))
            {
                this.Visible = true;
                //Graphics g3 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                //g3.DrawImageUnscaled(ss, mouse.X-target.Width/2, mouse.Y-target.Height/2, target.Width, target.Height);

                /*Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(,);
                Bitmap src = Image.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap;
                Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                                     cropRect,
                                     GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                Graphics g2 = frame.CreateGraphics();
                g2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0, target.Width, target.Height);*/


                result = ss.Clone(new Rectangle(mouse.X - target.Width / 2, mouse.Y - target.Height / 2, target.Width, target.Height),
                ss.PixelFormat);

                /*pictureBox1.Image = ss;
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

                pictureBox2.Image = result;
                pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;*/
                //ss.Dispose();
                return result;
            }
        }

        void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try { 
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                {
                    PictureBox frame = new PictureBox();
                    frame.Size = target.Size;
                    frame.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                    frame.Image = get_img();
                    frame.Location = new Point(mouse.X - (target.Width / 2), mouse.Y - (target.Height / 2));
                    this.Controls.Add(frame);
                    frame.BringToFront();
                    box.Add(frame);
                    go_transparant();

                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1) {
                    foreach(var i in box){
                        this.Controls.Remove(i);
                        i.Dispose();
                    }
                    box.Clear();
                    box = new List<PictureBox>();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);}
        }
        Point mouse = new Point();
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GetCursorPos(ref mouse);
                if (target != null)
                {
                    target.Location = new Point(mouse.X - target.Width / 2, mouse.Y - target.Height / 2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message); timer1.Stop(); timer1.Start(); }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you measure "too much RAM"? What is your tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are disposing of the objects, the memory will only actually be released when the Garbage Collector runs.  You can force this to happen explicitly by running the following code:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

However, it's not recommended to do this yourself as the Garbage Collector is intended to run when it is optimal.

Why do you need to explicitly reduce the memory used by your application when you have disposed your objects?

Comment: because after 20x "space" it takes about 400mb ram.
also, is it wise to put that in "1" operation?

Comment: I wouldn't personally recommend using at all, but if you were to place it anywhere it would be after you have disposed all the objects.  Don't run it individually for each dispose.

Comment: i tried 20x space (200mb ram) -> 1x "1" -> continue 20x space.
the result is the ram usage after that procedure is about 400mb, so even when the object destroyed it still takes memory.

Comment: Calling GC.Collect do not cause it to run imediatelly, check for other leaks as undisposed objects and also profile your application, but almost always is a good practice to keep yourself from calling GC.Collect

Comment: Oh, if you keep pressing space, what happens?

Comment: yeah, i add the GC after `box = new List<PictureBox>();` and it really works great. 

@bateloche i believe i disposed most of the object, but since the app capture the screen, it takes a lot of memory i guess.
if i keep pressing space, i got ERROR: out of memory and the apps crash.

Comment: @bateloche As you say, calling `GC.Collect` does not _necessarily_ cause immediate collection, but `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` causes the thread to pause until the garbage collector has finished, which is why I added it.

Comment: @MartinParkin Ok, in this case it help, you can get unresponsive for short periods but it's ok.

Comment: @DavinTimothyIvander just to add a good practice, if you wish to call the collector for every refresh, put it into a finally clause

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread
[How does C# manage memory allocated by a new operator inside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925141/how-does-c-sharp-manage-memory-allocated-by-a-new-operator-inside-a-loop)

My guess is that the memory is reserved and managed by the OS and/or the garbage collector and deppending on the usage of the app, it might stay "reserved" or be released.

We developed a program here that reads hundreds XML and connects to SAP Business One creating hundreds of transactions per day. We close connections and dispose objects as often as we can but the behaviour is always the same: The program starts at 1mb of ram but as soon as the proccess starts, it goes up to 1gb and never goes down.

The proccess occurs once every 24 hours at least (sometimes they force the proccess to start earlier and perform it 2 or 3 times in the same day) and the program uses the already reserved memory, it does not consume more.

Comment: yeah, in my case they consume more.. 
that's why, GC works fine for me.